# Highlight duplicates that share the same date

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I am trying to highlight duplicate addresses that share the same date.

[image]

I have tried these formulas in Conditional Formatting but they did not work.

=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(A:A=A1),-(B:B=B1))=-1,"No Duplicate","Duplicate")
=COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$21,A1,$A$1:$A$21,"<>",$B$1:$B$21,B1,$B$1:$B$21,"<>")>1

If you could also explain what the formula is doing would be awesome.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the 2nd formula but change $A$1 to $A$2,  $B$1 to $B$2, A1 to $A1 and B1 to $B1.

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$21,$A2,$A$2:$A$21,"<>",$B$2:$B$21,$B2,$B$2:$B$21,"<>")>1
```

Comment: Thanks Norie, it is working for these simple addresses but it's not working on more complex addresses for some reason. Is there a way for it not to find equals but most similar duplicates?

Comment: What do you mean by 'more complex addresses'?

Comment: `230 15th Street West, North Vancouver, British Columbia V7M 1S2`


Something like this, it's not picking up this address for some reason. Could it be some formatting issue?

Comment: The problem could be that  the addresses aren't actually matching, that could be caused by something like leading/trailing space, misspelt words etc.

Comment: I see, it's probably trailing spaces, because I checked and they are the exact same. Is there a way to format it?

Comment: Oh nevermind, I figured it out. The date had time stamps and they were different. That's why.

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
=SUM(($A2=$A$2:$A$10)*($B2=$B$2:$B$10))-1
```

[image]